# Can I use setModalPresentationStyle on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, presentmodalviewcontroller

I've been watching some of the iPhone development videos off iTunes specifically "Standford Fall 2011 iPad and iPhone App Development" and in lecture 15 Modal View Controller/test/Animation is says that setModalPresentationStyle is only to be used with iPad. I was wanting to do this with an iPhone app, is this possible? has there been an update since this was made that allows it? or is there another way I can simulate the features in this? Like the form sheet presentation style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, the `modalPresentationStyle` property of a view controller only applies to iPad. On iPhone and iPod touch, the presentation style is always fullscreen.

According to the documentation:

> The presentation style determines how a modally presented view
>   controller is displayed on the screen.  **On iPhone and iPod touch
>   devices, modal view controllers are always presented full-screen**, but
>   on iPad devices there are several different presentation options.  For
>   a list of possible presentation styles, and their compatibility with
>   the available transition styles, see the “UIModalPresentationStyle”
>   constant descriptions.

To get the same effect as a form sheet presentation on the iphone, the easiest is to present a modal view controller setting it's `modalTransitionStyle` set to `UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical` (which is the default transition style).

Comment: I take it this is the closest I will get to it then?

Comment: Unless you want to make a custom view that looks like a form and animate that onto the screen, yes. But then you would loose some functionality of the modal controller like being able to have a navigation stack for example.

Answer (score 1):

> On iPhone and iPod touch, modal view controllers are always presented full-screen, but on iPad there are several different presentation options.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom open source library for presenting form sheet on iPhone https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetController